# how to delete a tempfile later

Tags: python, temporary-files, python-webbrowser

On python 2.7, I am currently using the following code to send data via a post request to a webpage (unfortunately, I cannot really change this).  I prepare a string `data` which I prepare according to http://everydayscripting.blogspot.co.at/2009/09/python-jquery-open-browser-and-post.html, then write it to a file, and then open the file with `webbrowser.open`:

```
f = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
f.write(data)
f.close()
webbrowser.open(f.name)
time.sleep(1)
f.unlink(f.name)
```

However, I had to learn that sleeping a little sometimes is a little too little: I might delete the file before the data were submitted.

How can I avoid this?

One idea is, of course, to delete the file later, but when could this be?  The whole thing is a method in a class - is there a method that is relieably executed on destruction?  Or is it somehow possible to start the browser in a way so that it does not return, until the tab is closed?

Comment: The author of the post you linked used a context manager: ``with``. Can you do the same?

Comment: Oh, thanks for the hint.  I don't yet know what this does (I'm still a python newbie...).  I'll have to check!

Comment: @James - OP' s problem is that the file is deleted too early. How does the context manager help that?

Comment: @tdelaney IDK. The article he's pulling from uses it so I figured it's worth a shot before further digging. That's why I commented instead of answering.